# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf: How to keep line breaks from localization strings

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have localization strings with line breaks:

```
label.example=Text\nwith\nline\nbreaks
```

And i set the text using thymeleaf:

```
th:text="#{label.example}"
```

But the text is printed like:

```
Text with line breaks
```

But i want the text to appear like

```
Text
with
line
breaks
```

Why are my `\n` all deleted and not rendered into line breaks? How can i keep my line breaks? It is really important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because HTML considers a sequence of white space characters, including line breaks, as a single white space. Unless you tell it to preserve line breaks using CSS.

See the [`white-space` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: worked for me, also avoided using stuff like th:utext (which I don't like because of code execution).